# Features module import error

Tags: features

I have a bit complex work on Drupal 8 site, exporting everything via [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features)

I created groups using the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module. I also have a content type installed as plugin-a group content to the group named "Biz Articles". I have views relating to the groups and group contents.

So, when I try to use Features to export my work. I have the listed dependents modules below:

[image]

I import the module and enabled to the fresh Drupal 8 installed site. My intention is to test if my work would still be properly function and for me to easily back up everything using features.

Unluckily I am getting this unmet dependencies issue:

```
[error]  exception 'Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException' with message 'Configuration objects (core.entity_form_display.node.biz_page.default, core.entity_view_display.node.biz_page.default, field.field.node.biz_page.field_type_of_business, group.role.test_biz_group-670dfcb37, group.role.test_biz_group-a416e6833) provided by biz_articles have unmet dependencies' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal-8.2.6/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/UnmetDependenciesException.php:84
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal-8.2.6/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/ConfigInstaller.php(460): Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException::create('biz_articles', Array)
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal-8.2.6/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ProxyClass/Config/ConfigInstaller.php(132): Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigInstaller->checkConfigurationToInstall('module', 'biz_articles')
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal-8.2.6/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleInstaller.php(141): Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Config\ConfigInstaller->checkConfigurationToInstall('module', 'biz_articles')
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal-8.2.6/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ProxyClass/Extension/ModuleInstaller.php(83): Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array, true)
#4 /Users/johnreytanquinco/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/drupal/environment.inc(131): Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array, true)
#5 /Users/johnreytanquinco/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/drupal/environment.inc(198): drush_module_install(Array)
#6 /Users/johnreytanquinco/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/pm/pm.drush.inc(1168): drush_module_enable(Array)
#7 [internal function]: drush_pm_enable('biz_articles')
#8 /Users/johnreytanquinco/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(422): call_user_func_array('drush_pm_enable', Array)
#9 /Users/johnreytanquinco/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(231): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#10 [internal function]: drush_command('biz_articles')
#11 /Users/johnreytanquinco/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(199): call_user_func_array('drush_command', Array)
#12 /Users/johnreytanquinco/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(73): drush_dispatch(Array)
#13 /Users/johnreytanquinco/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/preflight.inc(93): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#14 /Users/johnreytanquinco/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(11): drush_main()
#15 {main}
```

That `biz_page` is my other content type, unused with some fields. One of the fields has reference to the taxonomy term that is also used in the Biz Article module.

What should be done to clear this unmet dependencies?